# how to pass my viewbag content (a huge table) from view to controller, in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am less experience and developing a portal, using ASP.NET MVC 5. After getting user request from portal, backend database query happened, and the data is display as a table in portal. If user want to save the table, user can click SAVE button to save it to user local computer.  Therefore, I need to send it as ViewBag.tables, and then store this table in local windows storage. When user press SAVE button, I can get this table back to controller, put it in excel, then transmit it to user for saving.

However, I am not able to send back the table from View, in `List<List<string>>` form,  to controller.  Please help me.  Thank you for your great effort.

//---------------------------------------------------------------------

From the controller, I put this table ( is a `List<list<string>>` ) into `ViewBag.tables` :

```
public ActionResult TestPage()
{
   ViewBag.tables = GlobalVariables.tableSend2View;
   return View();
}
```

//---------------------------------------------------------------------

Then, in view, javescript, it is store in windows storage, get from the storage,
filled in the Html Helper (Html.TextAreaFor), this value is ready to send to controller when user click SAVE button:

```
<script>
var storeTable = window['localStorage'];
storeTable.setItem("postBackTab", postBackTable);
var getJustAfterStore = storeTable.getItem("postBackTab");
var postBackFunc = document.getElementById("TB_ReturnTable_ID");
postBackFunc.value = getJustAfterStore;
</script>
```

//---------------------------------------------------------------------

in View, when the Save button is click :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveResult", "Management"))
{
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.postBacLis.POSTBACKLIST, new { @class = "form-control", style = "display: none;", id = "TB_ReturnTable_ID", name = "TB_ReturnTable_NAM" });
    <button type="Submit" class="btn-lg btn-info" , id="postBackButton">Save Result</button>
}
```

//---------------------------------------------------------------------

`m.postBacLis.POSTBACKLIST`, a variable of type `List<List<string>>`, is define in Model class:

```
private List<List<string>> _postBackList;
public List<List<string>> POSTBACKLIST
{
   get { return _postBackList; }
   set { _postBackList = value; }
}
```

//---------------------------------------------------------------------

However, I am not able to get value from my controller:

```
public ActionResult SaveResult(ManagementViewModel getPostBackTable)
{
   return View();
}
```

//---------------------------------------------------------------------

When I put a break point in return View();  , as in above,
from watch, getPostBackTable....., I get the following :

```
+ POSTBACKLIST  Count = 0  System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>
```

I am not able to get anything send back from view.

Please help.
Your effort is very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Cheers,
NewBuntu

Answer (score 0):

Let us first discuss how to pass data from a ASP.NET MVC View to Controller. There are four ways to pass the data from View to Controller which are explained below:

Traditional Approach: In this approach, we can use the request object of the HttpRequestBase class. This object contains the input field name and values as name-value pairs in case of the form submit. So we can easily get the values of the controls by their names using as indexer from the request object in the controller.
For example: Let's say you are having an input in the form with name 'txtName', then its values can be retrieved in controller from request object like below:

```
string strName = Request["txtName"].ToString();
```

Through FormCollection: We can also get post requested data by the FormCollection object. This object also has requested data as the name/value collection as the Request object.
For example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActionMethod1(FormCollection form) 
{
    string strName = form["txtName"].ToString();
    . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
 }
```

Through Parameters: We can also pass the input field names as parameters to the post action method by keeping the names same as the input field names. These parameters will have the values for those fields and the parameter types should be string. Also, there is no need to define the parameters in any specific sequence.
For example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActionMethod1(string txtName)
{
string strName = Convert.ToString(txtName);
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
}
```

In all of the above approaches, we need to even convert the non-string type to string type due to which if any parsing fails, then the entire action may fail here. Here we have to convert each value to avoid any exceptions but, in the below 4th approach of passing data from view to controller, it reduces the amount of code.

Strongly typed model binding to view: Here, we need to create a strongly typed view which will bind directly the model data to the various fields of the page.
For example:

Create a model with the required member variables.
Let's say we have a model named 'Person' with member variable named as 'Name'

Now pass the empty model to the view as parameter in the controller action.
For example:

```
public ActionResult GetName()
{
Person person = new Person();
return View(person);
}
```

Prepare the strongly typed view to display the model property values through html elements as below:
For example:

```
<div><%= Html.Encode(person.Name) %></div>
```

Create the action method that handles the POST request & processes the data.
For example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetPersonName(Person person)
{    
return Content(person.Name.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mojtaba Nava. I have a List of probably 10000 List inside, with approx. 300 items each list. All are strings.  May I have your suggestion which method is suitable for my requirement? the itmes number will varied each for each user request. Many thank for your help, Mojtaba Nava.